# how to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier when i add many UIView's as a subView to cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with heavy data. And I create `UITableViewCell` every time just like:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
```

And after that I add many `UIView`'s as a subView to `UITableViewCell` for e.g

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onDocumentLogoTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                button.frame = imageRect;
                button.tag = indexPath.row;
                [cell addSubview:button];
```

And like that I also add `UIImageView`. Problem is that my `UITableView` becomes very slow and application crashes sometime because of memory issue.

Could anyone suggest me proper way of using `UITableViewCell` when adding subView to it?

Comment: try this code

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: release button after adding it cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like as following:

**Before adding subview, First remove previous subviews**

```
for(UIView *sv in [cell.contentView subViews])
{
   [sv removefromsuperview];
}

[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

**Hope this Help!**

Answer (score 4):

Use this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you go for custom cell then you can use this method as

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            NSArray *nib;
        static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *theCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


        if(theCell== nil)
        {
            {
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<your custom cell xib name>" owner:self options:nil]; 
            }
            theCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

             theCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        }

        UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView*)[[theCell contentView] viewWithTag:101];
//assuming it has a image view with tag 101 you can use any thing

}
```